# How to control the style of uitable headers?

Tags: matlab, customization, matlab-uitable, matlab-app-designer, undocumented-behavior

Consider the following code that adds a table to a UIFigure:

```matlab
hF = uifigure();
hT = uitable(hF, 'Position',[1 1 72 112], ...
  'Data', [ (5:5:20).' + "K", 100+zeros(4,1) + "%" ], ...
  'ColumnName', [compose("\x0394T"), "SR"], 'RowName', [],...
  'ColumnWidth', {30,40});
addStyle( hT, uistyle('HorizontalAlignment', 'center')); % Added in R2019b
```

This results in:

[image]

As you can see above, the headers of the table are still left-justified, and have a smaller font size than the contents - which is quite unpleasant to look at. I would prefer having the header center-justified and having the same or larger font size.

My question is: **How can I change the text alignment and font size of the headers?**

I'm working with R2019b Update 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by executing several JS commands that modify the style of `<div class="mw-default-header-cell">` elements:

```matlab
% Get a webwindow handle:
hWin = struct(struct(struct(hF).Controller).PlatformHost).CEF;

% Execute some dojo commands:
hWin.executeJS('W = dojo.query("div[class=mw-default-header-cell]");');
hWin.executeJS('dojo.style(W[0], ''text-align'', ''center'');');
hWin.executeJS('dojo.style(W[1], ''text-align'', ''center'');');
hWin.executeJS('dojo.style(W[0], ''font-size'', ''12px'');');
hWin.executeJS('dojo.style(W[1], ''font-size'', ''12px'');');
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Note that `dojo.query("div[class=mw-default-header-cell]")` retrieves **all** divs that are table headers, so if there are multiple tables in the UIFigure, or headers one does not wish to modify, care must be taken with the indices (of `W`) to modify.